# Window function query on transaction data

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

This is my `ethereum_transaction_receipts` table in redshift:

```
CREATE TABLE "crypto_blockchains"."ethereum_transaction_receipts" (
    "hash" character varying(256),
    "block_number" bigint,
    "tx_time" timestamp without time zone,
    "event_generator_address" character varying(256),
    "event_hash" character varying(256),
    "event_decoded" character varying(256),
    "event_param_1" character varying(256),
    "event_param_2" character varying(256),
    "data" text,
    "token_from" character varying(256),
    "token_to" character varying(256),
    "token_amount" numeric(38,5)
    )
```

`tx_time` is the transaction time, `token_from` is from address, `token_to` is to address and `token_amount` is the transaction amount. I want the balance snapshot for each user for each day.

For example: If there is one transaction from A -> B on 2017-01-01 and another on A -> B on 2018-04-09, I want entries for each date between min and max date for the balances of A and B.

I have tried this query to get sum of `token amount` for `token from` user, same way I can calculate the sum of `token amount` for `token to` user and join them and subtract to get output,  but this query gives me one row per transaction and also I don't get details for the user who have stopped making transactions after a certain date.

```
select 
    date(tx_time) as date,
    token_from as addr,
    sum(nullif(token_amount,null)) over (partition by event_generator_address, token_from order by tx_time rows unbounded preceding) as amt 
    from crypto_blockchains.ethereum_transaction_receipts
    where event_decoded = 'Transfer'
```

Is there a better way to calculate balances per day using window functions.

Edit 1:
Sample Data:

```
token to,token from,token amount,tx_time
A,B,0.4,1/1/17
B,A,0.4,1/3/17
```

Desired Result:

```
user,balance,date
A,0,1/1/17
A,0.4,1/2/17
A,0,1/3/17
B,0,1/1/17
B,-0.4,1/2/17
B,0,1/3/17
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Sample data and result in edit

Comment: For what I understood of your data and desired result this has nothing to do with Windowing functions. You need a time/date table with every date to join with your data, and also, it is not clear why the last A and B result in desired output to be 0 for balance.

Comment: @JorgeCampos But I need the date dimension table to join with the user as well, How would I do that? Assuming there is a date table, can you suggest a query what the query would be to get to this result?

Comment: After using something as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range to generate the date range you just need to left join it with your data.

Comment: if I left join it with the current table I would get some rows which will only dates and not any other data, How would I arrive at daily balances of each user from that table?